# Detect the click event of home button in android (application launcher icon)

Tags: android, android-launcher

How to identify the click event in the application launcher icon in android? I need to go to home screen once the  user click on this icon. For example, assume this is the manifest file:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
..........
```

Using the following code  segment in `main activity` inside `onCreate()`

```
actionBar=getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

the application icon is click-able .I don't' have any way to detect the click event of this. Is this possible to do in android. Any suggestion to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to override `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // do what you want to be done on home button click event
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Additional details check on Android Developers: ["User Interface. Action Bar"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Comment: Thank you for your support. This is not a menu item. As I defined in the question it is application launcher icon  inside manifest file and it is place in the top left (in action bar) coner of the application. What I need is to detect the click event of this icon.

Comment: Hay It is correct. I did not notice android.R.id.home earlier. BTW thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this in onCreate(..)

```
     ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
     actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

     View ic=((View) findViewById(android.R.id.home));
        ic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"icon " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                                    //...               

            }
        });
```